# Problem at startup laravel9 system after git clone

Tags: php, github, laravel-9

After I made a git clone with my project, composer install and everything and php artisan serve I'm just getting three lines of footers like this: 2022 © Webshooter LM AB | Du använder version 4.1.9 | Laravel 9.12.2
screendump: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nH0N.jpg
If I change http://localhost:8000/app/ to http://localhost:8000/auth/login I come to the login page.
How to prevent that and to come to the information page directly as here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPYsd.jpg
Then address field is: http://localhost:8000
After that there is no problem, it only happens after a git clone.

Here some more information.

The clone:

git clone https://github.com/WebshooterLM/Webshooter_web_Laravel9.git

This is how it looks in my terminal just after the cloning:

```
Ralphs-MacBook:Webshooter_web_Laravel9 ralph$ pwd
/Users/ralph/laravel9-final/Webshooter_web_Laravel9
Ralphs-MacBook:Webshooter_web_Laravel9 ralph$ 

Ralphs-MacBook:Webshooter_web_Laravel9 ralph$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then I do php artisan serve

When I put localhost:8000 in adress-field the three footer-lines is all I see.

This is in the address field: http://localhost:8000/app/
It should only show http://localhost:8000

Here is the app.blade it gets stuck in:

```
@include('layouts.header')
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
</script>


    <base href="/">
    <div ui-view="navigation" class="hidden-print"></div>

    <div class="row hidden-print" ng-show="loadingState">
         <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-5 text-center text-muted padding-top-30 padding-bottom-30">
             <div class='uil-default-css'>
                 <div style='top:60px;left:96px;width:8px;height:80px;background:#00ABAA;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(0deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:0px;position:absolute;'></div>
                 <div style='top:60px;left:96px;width:8px;height:80px;background:#00ABAA;-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:0px;position:absolute;'></div>
                 <div style='top:60px;left:96px;width:8px;height:80px;background:#00ABAA;-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(180deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:0px;position:absolute;'></div>
                 <div style='top:60px;left:96px;width:8px;height:80px;background:#00ABAA;-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(270deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:0px;position:absolute;'></div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid" ng-hide="loadingState">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @include('alerts.factorymessages')
                <div ui-view="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@include('layouts.footer')
```

When I refresh it shows the big green crosses a short time.  After that the three footer-lines only shows. The crosses are rotating normally when it takes a while to load a page.

If I write http://localhost:8000/auth/login the login page comes up and after that all is working normal. The problem occurs only direct after a fresh clone.

What could be the problem?

Comment: That repo gives a `404` now. Are you sure you installed all packages? Does it use any frontend framework?

Comment: Well, you cannot reach the repo unless logged in to our private github. Also: I have checked different browsers and it happens on Mac Safari and Chrome but not on Firefox.
So it might be browser dependent but cannot see how?

Comment: nice_dev
The system works otherwise perfect. It looks like this but in an older Laravel5.3 version. https://test.webshooter.se that I have upgraded to Laravel9 with excellent result.

Comment: Ok, then it is difficult to predict or guess what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that.

Comment: It's pretty clearly not related to Git: Git won't be doing anything special here. It might be related to Git *not* doing anything special, but the rest of your system failing to do the special thing (whatever that is) until you tickle it just the right way (whatever *that* is) to make it do the special thing, and from then on it works. But you should not expect Git to do whatever that special thing is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure it's browser dependent. The error appears every time in Mac Safari but not in Firefox and only sometimes in Chrome. I downloaded MS Edge also and Webshooter comes up without problems. So I think it's Safari that's the problem.
Thank's all for your help anyway.